# Google as DNS set. Nslookup fails if not specified which server to use, but if the Google server is specified, it works

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

By Google as my DNS, I mean `8.8.8.8`. If I run `nslookup askubuntu.com`, it fails. But if I run `nslookup askubuntu.com 8.8.8.8` (the second parameter is the DNS server to use -- bypassing system settings), it works.

The problem is: If I run `nmcli device show wlp3s0`, it says IPV4.DNS is `8.8.8.8`. I suspect a problem with NetworkManager. I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop. I tried to use the same system from the live USB I installed it from and it works. It broke after I restarted the newly installed and updated system for the first time.

Comment: whats in your `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: `cat /etc/resolv.conf` says too many levels of symbolic links.

Comment: whoa there's your problem can you even `ls -ald /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: /etc/resolv.conf -> /etc/resolv.conf. Owner of the file/symlink is root.

Comment: @meccooll Solved now, check the my answer for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @meccoooll, I have found a solution to my problem:

Turns out that `resolv.conf` was a *symlink to itself*. I have never seen anything like this and I do not know how could that happen, but it did on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.

The fix is simple, run

```
# rm /etc/resolv.conf
# ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```